# How to Redirect Buy Now Button to View Cart instead of Shipping Address

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cart, addtocart, buy-now

[image]
When we click on Buy Now button it is redirecting to the shipping page
(https://vitalticks.in/checkout/#shipping)
[image]

But for us, it will be redirected to the View Cart page.
https://vitalticks.in/checkout/cart/
[image]

How can I achieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's behaving correct as it name suggests. **Buy now** generally means to finish shopping process faster that's why it's trying to skip cart page.

However if you want to redirect customer to cart after clicking the buy now button, copy add to cart html url to buy now button.  We can't suggest how to do it since not seeing the source code or that part.